# links in mvc2 cease to properly follow virtual path when loaded asynchronously in a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asynchronous, partial-views

I'm having a somewhat edge case problem in a large MVC2 application.  Initially, I had a single main view, which would load partial views while loading, which would contain links.  I have a local working environment, which uses an empty virtual path setting in the project settings page, and a staging environment, which (to better reflect the multi-application production environment) has an application-specific virtual path.  Everythign worked fine on both.  Recently, I have had reason to switch the partial view loading from on pageload to an asynch.  No other change was made.  The links continued to function locally, but when moved up to staging, neglected to add on the application-specific path setting, leading to all of them breaking.  I was able to find a workaround, based on using a significantly more thorough address, but I feel like there must be some sort of config setting somewhere that I'm missing that would fix this.

To be clearer (as I realize that the preceding may be a bit unclear), this particular error occurs only if the following are all true:

- The partial view containing the links must be put in place by an asych get call and jquery `.html()` function.  When it is loaded by MVC directly into the page, everything works fine.
- Must be on a server with virtual path set to something other than empty.  The problem here is somehow coming from not appending the string from the virtual path setting.  Indeed, if you manually enter the virtual path in the appropriate place to the links produced, they work fine.
- at least with respect to the partial view call, it must be in the form `PartialView("partialViewName", dataObject)` rather than `PartialView("~/Areas/appName/Views/controllerName/partialViewName.ascx", dataObject)`.  Swapping in the longer format does work.

Admittedly, I could just figure out by trial and error some way to swap the longer name in for the inner links as well and have everything more or less work, but it's not a terribly clean solution, I'm likely to need to do the same thing again in the future elsewhere, and I feel like there must be a better answer out there.  It seems like for whatever reason, the `PartialView()` call is failing to do some sort of link massaging that the `View()` call (which is wrapped around everything in the original non-asynch version) is handling automatically.  Does anyone know what I can do to tell the asynchronously-called `partialView()` to apply the same virtual path that the base `View()` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the answer.  It seems that relative links in asynch-served partial views are based on the link used by the `.post()` that called them - and that, in at least some cases, MVC manages to be more forgiving of post calls than of the links that proceed from them.  changing the get call address to properly cover the virtual path fixes it.